# Knockout JS : Setting value to Dropdown?

Tags: knockout.js

I have integrated knockout js in my project and now i am facing some issues in setting user selected values to Dropdown,

Code below:

```
<select id="regDobMonth" data-bind="options: RDOBM, optionsText: 'name', selectedOptions: selRDOBM" name="" class="date-sel month" tabindex="3"></select>
```

JS File :

```
RDOBY: ko.observableArray([{ name: "1986" }, { name: "1987" }, { name: "1988" }, { name: "1989" }, { name: "1990" }, { name: "1991" }, { name: "1992" }, { name: "1993" }, { name: "1994" }, { name: "1995" }, { name: "1996" }, { name: "1997" }, { name: "1998" }, { name: "1999" }, { name: "2000" }, { name: "2001" }]);
```

I am able to load these data to dropdown and able to select the selected values using ,

```
selRDOBY().name
```

But my problem is i want to set this value back to dropdown.

Eg: From backend system i am receiving 2010 as selected Year then i need to set this value to this dropdown.

How to do this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here appears to be that `selRDOBY` is an `observable` rather than a regular array or an `observableArray`. KnockoutJS's documentation on the [`selectedOptions` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/selectedOptions-binding.html) (which you're using to set the selected value) states:

> This should be an array (or an observable array). KO sets the element’s selected options to match the contents of the array. Any previous selection state will be overwritten.
>
> **If your parameter is an observable array, the binding will update the element’s selection whenever the array changes** (e.g., via push, pop or other observable array methods). If the parameter isn’t observable, it will only set the element’s selection state once and will not update it again later.
>
> Whether or not the parameter is an observable array, KO will detect when the user selects or deselects an item in the multi-select list, and will update the array to match. This is how you can read which of the options is selected.

Because of this, you need to redeclare your `selRDOBY` as an `observableArray`.

```
selRDOBY: ko.observableArray([]);
```

You'd need to modify your existing code to ensure that this change is repsected. So any instances of `selRDOBY(value)` may need to be changed to `selRDOBY([value])` or `selRDOBY.push(value)`.

Comment: thanks for your response.I think you havnt get what i mean. selRDOBY is for getting the selected dropdown value. By calling selRDOBY().name i am getting the selected dropdown value.My problem is like i want to reload the previously selected dropdown value to dropdown and make this value as selected.It will be good if you provide some examples.

Comment: @Cyber is `selRDOBY` an observableArray or just an observable?

Comment: Its selRDOBY: ko.observable('')

Comment: i have changed selRDOBY to selRDOBY:ko.observableArray([]), but how to access selected dropdown value .and i am also not able to set selected value again to dropdown.

Comment: @Cyber I don't really understand what you're trying to do. The selected dropdown value would be the one stored in `selRDOBY`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62821/discussion-between-cyber-and-james-donnelly).